# How does a child piped process behaves on signal to a parent?

Tags: linux, pipe, signals, child-process

I have an app in which the parent process starts a couple of a threads (plugins). And one of them periodically starts a child process and reads its output through a pipe using the `popen`.

Further, the parent process may be stopped by the SIGUSR1. All the plugins stop good except that one which uses the pipe: it throws the SIGSEGV somewhere in a `read` function.

I think this is because the child process stops on SIGUSR1 too, so the pipe become invalid. Am I right? An how may I resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you confirm the parent process is killed by SIGSEGV from a read call ?

Comment: @ZangMingJie, yes, but it does not killed actually because there is a handlers for signals. In any way the parent process got the SIGSEGV while calling the `read` in progress.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the bug causing the SIGSEGV was in another place: someone before me had programmed an `unload` function in this way:

```
void unload()
{
  stop_main_thread = 1;
  usleep(100000);
  LibLog::print("modem is disconnected");
}
```

while the thread function has a call `usleep(pause)` where the `pause` is set to 500000.

The `unload` function placed in one of a shared libraries and called when a program is about to shutdown. So when the `unload` function is done, so-file is unloaded the thread function try to do something yet with the known result.

Changing the `usleep` call in the `unload` to the `pthread_join` solves my issue.